# I am replacing value "Kumar" with "Singh" while Iterating ArrayList using Java 7, How it will convert using Java 8 Stream API?

Tags: java-8

```
ArrayList<String> namesList1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList( "Amar", "Jeet", "Kumar") );

    for(int i=0; i < namesList1.size(); i++){
        if(namesList1.get(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Kumar")) {
            namesList1.set(i, "Singh");
        }
    }
```

Comment: What code have you written so far? What research have you performed?

Comment: This isn’t a free code writing service, show us what you have done so far and explain what your issue is and we can help you from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below:

**Method:1**

```
 namesList1.forEach(name -> {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Kumar")) {
            namesList1.set(namesList1.indexOf(name), "Singh");
        }
    });
    System.out.println(namesList1);
```

---

**Method :2** (Suggested by @Holger)

```
namesList1.replaceAll(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase("Kumar")? "Singh": s);
System.out.println(namesList1);
```

Comment: Please add an explanation how this solves the issue, giving some context to an answer gives it more quality and is more helpful to others than an answer that is just some code.

Comment: Why is every `set` call wrapped in a `println` statement? Besides that, performing another `indexOf` for every match is rather inefficient and you can do it even simpler using `namesList1.replaceAll(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase("Kumar")? "Singh": s);` anyway.